# How execute one animation then the other

Tags: android, animation

I do not want my two animals to start at the same time and one after the other. 
Do you have any ideas?

My animations :

**Fade1**

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromAlpha="1.0"
       android:toAlpha="0.0"
       android:duration="1500"
/>
```

**Fade2**

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromAlpha="1.0"
       android:toAlpha="0.0"
       android:duration="3000"
/>
```

**My idea no work**

```
 private void animations_sequencing(){
        //The first anim start
        try{
            text.setText("Hello");
            text.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Main2Activity.this, R.anim.fade1));
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //The first anim is end, the seconde anim start
        try{
            text.setText("World");
            text.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Main2Activity.this, R.anim.fade2));
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it :

```
Animation anim2;

private void anim(){

    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Main2Activity.this, R.anim.fade);
        anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Main2Activity.this, R.anim.fade2);

        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            text.setText("World");
            text.startAnimation(anim2);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }

    });
        text.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement `setAnimationListener` to capture when animation end.

```
text.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Main2Activity.this, R.anim.fade1).setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //start second animation
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            }));
```